# JQuery and caching not loading correctly with maxCDN?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

This is my website: https://infosec-conferences.com/

Each of the events has a dropdown that don't work.

The developer console reports that the error is due to:

```
dropdown.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

So, I've diagnosed that the problem is due to JQuery not loading correctly which is placed at the top of the page, but here's the very odd thing - I can't clear or update the JQuery cache of my WordPress website which uses maxCDN and W3TC.

Clearing the cache works for the rest of the site but won't work for the jquery-core which is loaded via this functions.php command:

```
function Remove_JQuery_Migrate( &$scripts) {
    if(!is_admin()) {
        $scripts->remove( 'jquery');
        $scripts->add( 'jquery', false, array( 'jquery-core' ), '3.2.1' );
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_default_scripts', 'Remove_JQuery_Migrate' );
```

My question might be a bit vague and I'm hoping that I'll get lucky in that someone has had this 'problem'

Any idea/ thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace the `$` to `jQuery` in these 3 jquery files.

1. smooth-scroll.js
2. backtotop.js
3. directory-dropdown.js

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH - saved me a bunch of time.

Comment: glad to help you :)